# Running a simple WLST embebbed java from Netbeans connecting with weblogic 12c

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic12c, wlst

this is my first post.  I`m trying to execute a simple java program from Netbeans that connect with Weblogic 12c in Windows 10, with no success.I checked starckoverflow with no luck. Is for a college work.

1)I installed Netbeans 8.2 with java jdk1.8.0_161 and jre.8.0_161
2)I installed Weblogic 12.c
3) Weblogic start and stop works fine. wlst.cmd works fine to. I can connect manually and execute scripts (connect('weblogic', 'weblogic', 'localhost:7001'))

4) Enviroment is configured, Ive checked manually all the scripts below

```
 C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>setWlstEnv
Execute... setWlstEnv.cmd
Execute... setWlstEnv_internal.cmd
Execute... setHomeDirs.cmd
Execute... commBaseEnv.cmd
```

[Enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq4K3.png)

5) C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib is in the classpath, the weblogic.jar is in the classpath. I added all the jars too to the project:
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib

[Netbeans project Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpzuL.png)

6) JAVA PROGRAM:

package weblogic;

import weblogic.management.scripting.WLST;
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;

public class WEBLOGIC {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WEBLOGIC wrapper = new WEBLOGIC();
    wrapper.doSomething();
}

public void doSomething() {
    WLST.ensureInterpreter();
    WLSTInterpreter interpreter = WLST.getWLSTInterpreter();
    interpreter.exec("connect('weblogic', 'weblogic', 'localhost:7001')");
    interpreter.exec("ls()");
}
```

}

7)[Netbeans Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pycn.png)

I can't find info related even in google or stackoverflow. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Several different versions of weblogic.jar in the classpath, produced the runtime error: No such Field Error. With only one (the right one) works fine.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-how-to-solve-suchfielderror/

> Establish the connection :  Connection URL :
>   connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:7001') Connecting to
>   t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ... Successfully connected to
>   Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'ClassicDomain'.
>
> Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the  server. To
>   ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or  Admin port should be
>   used instead.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)